# Max and min Dates

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using trial version of devExpress controls. I have two calendar controls on one page. I want that Calendar 1 selected date is always less than Calendar' 2 selected date and Calendar 2 selected date is always greater than Calendar 1 selected date.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: I assume your post is wrong, how can be calendar 1 less than calendar 2 and also calendar 2 less than calendar 1?

Comment: You could write a never-ending loop, but in traditional development circles this is often frowned upon :-) Just kidding, please review the question and maybe look at the DevEpress documentation for update or change events

Comment: sorry, just updated question.... devexpress calendar is similar to asp.net calendar. how can I control the dates ?

Comment: Validators and autopostbacks (as Dirk suggests).  Place an ASP.NET validator that checks the values and some helper function in the SelectionChanged (or whatever the event is called) event to correlate the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use [ASPxDateEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxDateEdittopic) control. Try this for client side checking:

```
<dxe:ASPxDateEdit ClientInstanceName="cal1" runat="server">
    <ClientSideEvents DateChanged=
            "function(s,e) {
                if (s.GetDate() >= cal2.GetDate()) 
                {
                    s.SetIsValid(false);
                    s.SetErrorText("cal1 >= cal2");
                }            
            }" 
    />
</dxe:ASPxDateEdit>

<dxe:ASPxDateEdit ClientInstanceName="cal2" runat="server">
    <ClientSideEvents DateChanged=
            "function(s,e) {
                if (s.GetDate() <= cal1.GetDate()) 
                {
                    s.SetIsValid(false);
                    s.SetErrorText("cal1 >= cal2");
                }            
            }" 
    />
</dxe:ASPxDateEdit>
```

You should implement server side validation as well.

[ASPxClientDateEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientDateEdittopic)  and [DateEditClientSideEvents](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsDateEditClientSideEventsMembersTopicAll) documentation.